# Picture в JavaScript-ID3-Reader

Tags: изображения, javascript, файлы

Использую библиотеку [JavaScript-ID3-Reader](https://github.com/aadsm/JavaScript-ID3-Reader) чтобы забирать cover из mp3 трека. В [примере](http://web.ist.utl.pt/antonio.afonso/www.aadsm.net/libraries/id3/) все работает и возвращаемый объект с данными имеет свойство `picture`

[image: объект]

но когда я использую его в своём проекте то свойства `picture` уже нет

[image: объект].

Делаю все так как и в примере, но почему этого свойства там нет?

Comment: Может быть потому что у композиции нет ковера? Песни то вы разные загружаете.

Comment: нет, специально скачал трек с примера и проверил его через редактор, ковер там точно есть.